# Does a service worker need to cache manifest icons that are not used by the core of the PWA?

Tags: caching, icons, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, favicon

This question may seem quite essential.
However, I could not find an answer in any of the official Progressive Web Application (PWA) documentation.

The `manifest.json` of my PWA contains quite a bit of icons and even a fairly large `screenshot.png` that are not essential to the core of the PWA.

```json
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/android-chrome-512x512.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/android-chrome-192x192.maskable.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/apple-touch-icon.png",
            "sizes": "180x180",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ],
    "screenshots": [
        {
            "src": "./assets/static/images/screenshot.png",
            "sizes": "1080x2220",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
```

Only one of the above icons is referred by the `index.html` of my single page PWA:

```html
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/static/images/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
```

But there are even a whole lot more icons mainly for Microsoft Windows and the Apple Safari browser that are even not referred by the `manifest.json`. The Microsoft Windows icons are listed only in the `browserconfig.xml` file:

```html
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/static/images/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/static/images/favicon-32x32.png"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/static/images/favicon-16x16.png"/>
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="./assets/static/images/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#379"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="./assets/static/images/browserconfig.xml"/>
```

On the other hand, my PWA has its own set of application icons that are not listed in the `manifest.json` but of course are cached by the `service-worker.js`; no problem there.

The targets of my PWA are mobile Android & iOS, with occasionally some Internet-connected desktop computers.

My question refers mainly to the first-mentioned set of icons: **Do these Android and iOS icons and the screenshot need to be cached by the `service-worker.js` even if the core of the PWA does not require these to function well?**

Which would be equivalent to asking: Do the respective operating systems save the installation icons even when these are not cached by the `service-worker.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The brief answer is **"no,"** none of the (fav)icons or screenshots should be cached by the `service-worker.js` if the PWA will not use these.

Moreover, `manifest.json` should only refer to icons targeting the Android and/or Chrome browser. Hence, **`apple-touch-icon.png` should not be mentioned in the `manifest.json`.**

For iOS, it suffices to place the `apple-touch-icon.png` in the root folder of the `scope` of your application. The same holds true for `favicon.ico`.

There are some more rules for Windows and Mac OS X user agents. These can easily be checked by following the guidelines of this [**favicon generator**](https://realfavicongenerator.net) or by proving your PWA URL to its [**favicon checker**](https://realfavicongenerator.net).

For example, it told me that the following line is best best kept out of `index.html`:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico"/>
```

**The only exception** to this are the `favicon-32x32.png` and `favicon-16x16.png` icons that are referred to in `index.html`. These two icons should be cached, as desktop browser will fetch these as tab icons.

Furthermore, the `service-worker.js` should also not cache itself.

Finally, significant icon size reductions can be achieved by converting the images from RGB colour space to an **indexed colour palette** of for example 24 colours. This can be done using the free image editor [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org). When exporting the images with GIMP, **deselect metadata and thumbnail generation.**